# How to find a source of a file in AS/400?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have created a table using STRSQL, inserted data into the table. Now i want to see the source of the table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The Database component of ACS, or the older IBM iSeries Access for Windows, has a "Generate SQL" function.

This can be used with DDL defined tables or with DDS defined PF/LF.

In v7.1 (w/ Db PTF level 23) and later, there's a stored procedure, [QSYS2.GENERATE_SQL_OBJECTS](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1118355)

Finally, all the above functionality is actually using the [Generate Data Definition Language (QSQGNDDL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qsqgnddl.htm) system API under the covers.  You may also call it from your own programs.